# How to stop iOS app from scrolling up

Tags: ios, autolayout, scrollview

I made a Content View inside Scroll View added constraints using common Autolayout with UIScrollView tutorials. But how do I stop my Scrollview from scrolling up when there is no content, the view slides down to content, but I want to disable scrolling up, I searched for the answer but there is none to be found, please help.

Comment: Will "scrollView.scrollEnabled = false" do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ability to scroll slightly beyond the content in a [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/) is referred to as "bouncing".

> The scroll view must know the size of the content view so it knows when to stop scrolling; by default, it “bounces” back when scrolling exceeds the bounds of the content.

You need to set bounces to no:

> If the value of [bounces] is YES, the scroll view bounces when it encounters a boundary of the content. Bouncing visually indicates that scrolling has reached an edge of the content. If the value is NO, scrolling stops immediately at the content boundary without bouncing. The default value is YES

```
scrollView.bounces = NO;
```